# Cannot install linux ic on Linux redhat 6 virtual machine on windows hyper-v

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have windows 2008 r2 with hyper v role.
I created a rhel6 virtual machine, however when I try to install Linux Integration services following Microsoft's instructions I get this error:

```
ls: cannot access kmod-microsoft-hyper-v-rhel6-43.1.x86_64.rpm No such file or directory
ls: cannot access microsoft-hyper-v-rhel6-43.1.x86_64.rpm No such file or directory
RPM`s are missing
```

I verified that both files are located in the same folder as the install.sh script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found 
http://chkchaitu.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/rhelcentos6-2-on-hyper-v-2k8-r2-with-lic-v3-2/

After installing Linux Integration Services v 3.2 found that CD room is not working - solution to this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600152

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the install.sh script?
Maybe he is looking somewhere else than it's own directory ;).

Comment: in script there is a command kmodrpm='ls kmod-microsoft.....rpm' not shure where it points

Comment: Linux is wierd thing :@ Copied everything to root and then executed script from media and everything worked good.

Answer (score 0):

The path for the directories may be different than in which the script looks for.

Comment: script uses ls commant to define location, but I`m not shure how it works. Never done anything with linux before.